# Deployment with Workbench - Failure due to special character in process name

Tags: deployment, workbench

I am deploying the components using workbench. One of the components is 'case' object that has got business process named "Complaints & Enquiries". When trying to deploy the package, getting below error.

"An object 'Case.Complaints & Enquiries' of type BusinessProcess was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory"

Case.Complaints & Enquiries is present inside case.object OBJECT file.

Did anyone face similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "escape" ampersand (`&`) in your package.xml with a "character entity." This is because XML uses `&` as a special character to represent other characters, and must therefore itself be escaped. In your package.xml, it should be `Case.Complaints &amp; Enquiries`. In the Case.object file, you must also observe this rule.

Comment: Yes. I can see "<members>Case.Complaints &amp; Enquiries</members>" in package.xml and   " <businessProcesses>
        <fullName>Complaints %26 Enquiries</fullName>
        <description>Complaints &amp; Enquiries</description>
        <isActive>true</isActive> " in case.object OBJECT file.

Comment: I renamed <fullName>Complaints %26 Enquiries</fullName> to fullName>Complaints &amp; Enquiries</fullName>. it worked.

Comment: @SFDClearner Odd, that should work. I've always recommended avoiding the use of `&` for various reasons. Did you manually create/edit this file, or did it come from a previous API call?

Comment: I downloaded the case.object OBJECT metadata file with the help of 'Salesforce inspector' and edited the full name. Will make sure not to use '&' in future.